# Similar to traveling salesman problem? Flooding console with output?

Tags: time, big-o

**DISCLAIMER** This is for a crypto program for one of my classes and possibly personal use. However I am not being graded on it.

I already cracked this code, and it is a random caeser cypher.
Q PC JI UQTGF TQBMU SIX. XMGS QJ UMQJ IKGT?

Now to solve this computationally using dictionaries wouldn't it be similar to the traveling salesman problem? O(n!) for a worst case scenario. Also, since the computer has no way of knowing if something is correct wouldn't I have to spit every ending permutation out for review? Or should I put some sort of lower bounds for human review? Like at least a 40% match?

Comment: If it's really a Caesar cipher, there are only 25 possible decryptions; do them all and look up the words in a dictionary.

Comment: CaeserCyphers can have random shifting, not just mod based.

Answer (score 0):

Caesar Ciphers are simply taking letters and replacing them with letters shifted `s` position down.

So: 
For each letter in the alphabet, `a`,

You iterate `a` times.

Then for each of the `v` words in the cipher, you must go through `d` words in the dictionary.

A cycle through the words, ignoring compressions and whatnot, would yield a complexity of `O(a*v*d)`, and if `a==26`, `O(v*d)`.  However, the complexity is essentially based on HOW YOUR DICTIONARY ALGORITHM WORKS- `O( is_sentence_valid) == O(cipher_solver)`